# Using firebase for persistent storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm working on a IOT project, where we are evaluating to use firebase. We have a prototype implemented which works fine for real time data. Since the data is critical for client they want to be able to retrieve the data at later point of date. I couldn't find much about a persistent storage in the firebase website, any of you have idea on if we can use firebase alone or do we need to transfer it to you a cloud based store like google cloud store, if so what is the reliable time for which firebase will hold the data. Assuming you choose the right plan.

Thanks
Kamal

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/fNzNtn4pJXM

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I had done it thinking that groups is officially handled by Firebase employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a persistent database. While you certainly can setup a way to transfer the data to an archive, if you structure your data correctly, there shouldn't be any need to do so. You haven't really indicated what those requirements are, however, so it is difficult to thoroughly answer your question. (If you have one.)

There have been several demonstrations of using Firebase as part of an IoT infrastructure. Consider, for example [this presentation by Jenny Tong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RjfoNnxKGA&list=PLOU2XLYxmsILhJSXjIpNxBE5HkND3wFPL&index=24) ([@mimming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839465/mimming)) about doing exactly this.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner It helps